# Pushing/Migrating your local Drupal site to a live-site

Tags: web-hosting, rewrite, drupal

- I have installed drupal on my localmachine(ubuntu, Xampp), at localhost.
- Path and Pathauto modules are active (a module to produce friendly URLs).

**Migrating/Pushing my local install to the www.mysite.com**

- Exported SQL from phpMyadmin(localhost).
- Made a new DB at live site (I think a different name from the localhost-DB does not create any problem).
- Imported SQL into phpMyadmin, (mysite).
- Changed the username-password-DBname in the  sites/default/settings.php in drupal folder.
- Now, uploaded the drupal folder and all its content into the /www of the "mysite.com".

Visited the URL www.mysite.com, site looks same as on my localhost, good.

But --

1. I made a tryPage on my
   localhost/drupal, for which
   pathauto(cleanURL) recommended the
   URL "content/trypage" which i
   explicitly changed to "trypage", so
   that absolute link to the page is
   "localhost/drupal/trypage" and not
   "localhost/drupal/content/trypage".
   Now When i click the trypage link on the mysite,
   it open's it in-reference to my
   localhost, my local-pages are
   opened. That is, when I click
   newpage on the mysite.com, the URL
   requested is
   "localhost/drupal/newpage" and not
   "www.mysite.com/newpage".

   Do you think it is coz of the SEO
   friendly URL generation issue, the
   Pathauto module.

   *Anyways how do i solve this*
   If I make my "localhost/drupal" to open from same URL (mysite.com), i dont know how
   to do that exactly, i think by configuring
   vhosts. But if i do that, then the URL
   www.mysite.com where will it take
   me, local or online.
2. Now If i add new modules, new content, new pages, and new books on my localhost site, and wish to update mysite.com, do i have to redo SQL export/import everytime, and use a software like rsync/sitecopy(), to upload the folders on the live site. How do i solve this.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled. You also need to change the base URL in /sites/default/settings.php

Comment: yes mod_rewrite is enabled, as i guess ie y pathauto works. 2. "$base_url = 'http://mysite.com'"; does adding this line will do. any specific place to add this. thanks

Comment: $base_url = 'http://www.example.com'; // NO trailing slash!

Comment: $base_url = http: // mysite.com

Comment: which setting.php needs the base_url change, the one on localmachine or the one on live-site

Comment: On the live site

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if you clear the cache on the live site then you'll find the links suddenly point to the right server. I've seen instances where menu entries were generated on a copied site which pointed to the old URL.

I generally have Devel and Admin Menu modules so "Flush caches" is right there in the top left admin_menu menu. Or you could simply not include the cache_* tables when you copy your MySQL up.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

"content/title" in the pathauto URL looks like the out-of-the-box default. Check the configuration for pathauto->nodes.

Also, cache-clearing, as Chris suggests. It can correct many odd problems.